# Local "statusline" override problem

Tags: vimscript, autocmd, statusline, setlocal

I'm currently writing a plugin, and got stuck with this problem.

My plugin opens a new window with all local options I want, but also sets the `statusline` option to display some useful information. Vim permits to set the `statusline` option locally to a window, and this is what I need.

The problem is the race condition between other statusline plugins (like lightline etc.) which override my statusline. Most of these plugins us `WinEnter,BufEnter` autocmds that trigger their `update` function.

Is there a way to "monopolize" the statusline for local windows?

Comment: Remove the offending plugin, or consult plugin's docs to see if it's possible to exclude some windows. You can't just "forbid", you'd rather "ask not to do".

Comment: @Matt I'm writing a plugin with my **local statusline** that appears when my plugin is running. Why should I force users to remove their statusline plugin?

Comment: You can provide a function to get info of your plugin, users can use it to construct their own `statusline` in whatever way they like.

Comment: Obviously, because you have the "race condition" with this plugin. Lightline expects that you add some "indicator component" onto it, while you're trying to replace it. To be compliant, you should export some sort of `MypluginStatusline()` instead.

Comment: @dedowsdi yes, but my info is not just a one-character indicator, I need the entire statusline (see example https://github.com/ctrlpvim/ctrlp.vim)

Comment: @Matt Lightline is an example. I don't care which plugin the user uses for the statusline. The workaround should be universal for my local windows. When you install ```ctrlp.vim``` plugin, they provide their own statusline. In a nutshell, this plugin literally is the ```getchar()``` function in a infinite loop that does not permit you to interact with the window because it ignores non printable characters like ```ctrl+key,``` so the other plugins never trigger, that's why they do not worry about race condition.

Comment: This is irrelevant. As a matter of fact, you have some sort of a "clash for a system resource". You may complain that it's the other plugins who behave badly (and personally I'm even agree with this), but it doesn't change anything. So comply or <strike>begone</strike> remove it.